# Is it possible to provide access rights to all the dashboards inside one database?

Tags: apache-superset, access-rights

There are two databases configured on superset. I want to have a role that has access to all the dashboards/slices on one database, but not on the other one.
Let's say that I want to provide access to a db called `main`.

Is providing `datasource access on [main].(id:1)` supposed to grant access to all the dashboards and slices on `main`?

At the moment it doesn't work that way, so I'm wondering what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`database access on [main].(id:1)` will grant access to all the dashboards and slices on your `main` db.

So what you want is `database access on [main].(id:1)` rather than `datasource access on [main].(id:1)`

As of v. 0.20.0 granting such access means that users will be able to view Slices and Dashboards that are based on the granted DB when provided a direct link to those visualizations. However, they will not be able to view the list of these Slices and Dashboards.

Comment: I granted `database access on [main].(id:1)`. Now I'm able to access dashboards and slices using direct link, but the lists of Dashboards and Slices are still empty.  
  
From reading the code it looks like it wasn't implemented yet.

Comment: @dmigo yep - I've tried to add explicit List/View access on Tables - and the associated tables didn't show up for me either. Which part of the code pointed out to the fact it wasn't implemented yet?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/blob/master/superset/views/core.py) you can find a couple of comments like `# TODO(bogdan): add \`schema_access\` support here`

Comment: That indeed settles it then. Edited my answer to clarify.